# Solution dedicated to storing lots of ssh keys

Tags: ssh, security

Imagine you need to talk to many servers over internet and you need to keep the ssh keys and also relevant certificate of talking to different things (like a database on that server) of that server.

Currently we are storing these keys on the disk but I am wondering if there exist a solution dedicated to this problem? openstack key stone project looks interesting but I am wondering if there is a more generic solution available specially if it is open source?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with secpanel. Not the "PROTECT YOUR SERVER IN 60 SECONDS" with the same name but the open source SSH gui for unix (http://themediahost.de/secpanel/)